# Find length of linestring in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, distance, measure

I have a feature layer using OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature with OpenLayers.Handler.Path. I want to measure the real length of the path produced. Everything I find on Google tells me to use OpenLayers.Control.Measure, but this is not what I want because it does not provide an editable path.

So how do I measure the DrawFeature line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, there is a method called getLength() which can be called to get the length of the geometry.